# set variable as today and yesterday in pentaho di

Tags: variables, pentaho

I am creating a transformation in pentaho di to extract data from google analytics. I need to set in "Query Definition" the start date and end date as yesterday and today. I understand this can be done by create two varialbes e.g. ${todsy},${yesterday}. However, I don't know how to set these to change values dynamically at every run. ANy idea on how to do this?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of an easy way to do this. The first thing is that you can't declare and use the variables in the same transformation. I would suggest you to approach this problem in the following way:

1. Create a transformation before this one, say "set variables transformation". In this transformation you will set the variables.
2. You can use `Get System Info` step to set today's and yesterday's dates as the variables. Use `copy rows to result` step to pass these rows to the next transformation.
3. In the next transformation, which will be the one you have attached the screenshot of, use the `Get Variables` step and use these variables in your input step. Or you can use `Get rows from result` step as well.

You don't need to worry about the dates now, because dates will be generated and your variables get the values dynamically.

You can check this article if you want to learn more about how to pass the values from one transformation to another:
https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

for that, you have to use a job, add the first transformation and inside it use 
 **get system info** step then add today's and yesterday's date as a variable, and link to the **set variable** step. Set the scope of variable as **parent job**,
in second job use **get variables **.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to solve this myself and the way I ended up doing it is as follows:

I created a transformation (called 'set formatted_today variable') the transformation contains two objects:

1. The transformation contained a 'table input' object with a query like:

   `select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI') as formatted_today`
2. The output of my 'table input' goes to a 'set variables' object, you can use the 'get fields button to wire the fields you've named in your query to the variable you want to set. In this case, my field is called 'formatted_today' and so is my variable.

In my main job, I have a 'set session variables' object that creates my 'formatted_today' variable.

Immediately after it, I call my 'set formatted_today variable' transformation

Anywhere I need this variable I insert `${formatted_today}` in the text